# Android - View getHeight in Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I have a class which extends LinearLayout

```
public MyLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // Some override functions
    @Override
    public void ...
}
```

Since it's a custom class, I create unit test to verify its layout_weight, although none of the override functions modify it.

```
@Test
public void testWeight() {
    View view_1 = new View(mContext);
    view_1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(mWidth_1, 0, mWeight_1));
    // Attempt 5
    view_1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Never get called
            view_1.getHeight();
        }
    });

    View view_2 = new View(mContext);
    view_2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(mWidth_2, 0, mWeight_2));

    MyLayout myLayout = new MyLayout(mContext);
    myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    myLayout.addView(view_1);
    myLayout.addView(view_2);

    // Attempt 1
    myLayout.onFinishInflate()
    view_1.getHeight();

    // Attempt 2
    myLayout.layout(0, 0, 1080, 1920);
    view_1.getHeight();

    // Attempt 3
    myLayout.draw(new Canvas());
    view_1.getHeight();

    // Attempt 4
    myLayout.onWindowFocusChanged(true);
    view_1.getHeight();

    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
}
```

I understand that the `view` might not get inflated up to some point of its life cycle, but all the attempts I made return 0. What's the proper way to get the view dimension without a `Activity`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attempt 5 should work.

Comment: No, it does not work either. Actually, it never gets called. I updated the code.

Comment: Add your imports, otherwise it's not clear what you're doing. Also, add test setup method.

Comment: More to it, what you're trying to test? What's your scenario?

Comment: I am trying to verify that the child view dimension is set properly by the weight. My custom class which is MyLayout does not modify this attribute, I am sure it's work correctly because I can see it in Layout Editor and when the app is launched. But I want to test it in unit test level.

Comment: You are setting the height to 0 which mean the view will never become visible!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar The view is inside a LinearLayout and its weight is set, therefore, its height will be managed by the LinearLayout.

Comment: Oops sorry i missed that. Are you sure your unit test and `testWeight()` method is getting called. Also you should move attempt 5 after the line `myLayout.addView(view_1);`

Comment: I will give it a try and report the result here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, moving the attempt 5 around does not work either. But I found an alternative, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question. The workaround I found is to create an Activity and add the custom layout I want to test. Then use `ActivityTestRule` to launch the activity.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyTestActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MyTestActivity.class);
```

The views will be inflated and ready for test before the `@Test` method gets run. See more, [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html).